# How to detect a different tab has been clicked in A TTabControl?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I just want to know if on `TTabControl` click, a different tab other than the current tab has been clicked. Ideas are most welcome.

*P.S. Please don't ask for code. I am only asking for ideas. Also, posting codes in my company is frowned upon. ( my prev posts were done in Secret)*

Comment: lets get real here, any code you have on TTabbedPane cannot be that uber secret, given that you're still working in Delphi 7.

Comment: I don't know of any component named `TTabbedPane` neither does google, do you mean `TTabControl`, `TTabSheet` or even gasp `TTabbedNotebook`?

Comment: my mistake . it is TTabControl

Comment: Why not use the OnChange event?

Comment: @CyprUS: If your question is about TTabControl then why do you rollback your question to a version talking about (both of) tabbedPane and TTABbedControl but **not** about TTabControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from `TTabControl.OnChange` you might also want to consider [`TTablControl.OnChanging`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomTabControl_OnChanging.html):

> Write an OnChanging event handler to take specific action immediately *before* the selected tab changes.

Comment: thanks andriy m , i had actually written a code of about 50 lines to do the same. but your method is far better

Answer (score 10):

from '[TTabControl.OnChange Event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TTabControl_OnChange.html)'

> Write an OnChange event handler to take specific action immediately
>   after the selected tab changes.